# Error installing IBM Mobile First Studio 7.1 on Mac

Tags: eclipse-plugin, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, mobilefirst-studio

OS Version : MAC OS Sierra 10.12.1 ,

JDK : 1.8 ,

Eclipse :  Kepler SR2

The error is during the installation of the plugin :

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: IBM Dojo Mobile Tools 7.1.0.00-20160726-1659 (com.ibm.imp.dojo.tools.licensed.feature.feature.group 7.1.0.00-20160726-1659)
  Missing requirement: Model Plug-in 8.0.0.v20160726_1542 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.model 8.0.0.v20160726_1542) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.type.core [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Rich Page Editor - Dojo extensions 1.1.500.v20160726_1542 (com.ibm.etools.rpe.dojo 1.1.500.v20160726_1542)
    To: bundle com.ibm.etools.webtools.model [8.0.0,9.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Dojo Web Tools 2.1.200.v20160726_1542 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.dojo.feature.feature.group 2.1.200.v20160726_1542)
    To: com.ibm.etools.rpe.dojo [1.1.500.v20160726_1542]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM Dojo Mobile Tools 7.1.0.00-20160726-1659 (com.ibm.imp.dojo.tools.licensed.feature.feature.group 7.1.0.00-20160726-1659)
    To: com.ibm.etools.webtools.dojo.feature.feature.group 1.0.0
```

If someone has faced the issue please let me know.....any help appreciated

Comment: Is your Mac have access to internet?  If not, you can try to install the Eclipse, then MFP Studio on a different Mac machine with internet access.  Then copy the Eclipse directory from the other machine onto this machine.

Comment: This maybe correct. I cannot test it now. Its govt machine. I can test this only after weekend. I will test it on Monday and let you know in 2 days.There is definitely internet connection to that machine, but the downloads may be restricted.

Comment: Try adding proxy to the eclipse, if there is one available

Comment: @tyly I tried installing again with proxy disabled. Still the same error. I got the eclipse installed on another mac. Will the studio be fully functional if I import it from other mac ?

Comment: @DonWoodward yes the Studio installation is contained within the Eclipse folder so you should be able to copy the Eclipse folder from the other machine into this one.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm facing a similar problem with IBM MobileFirst CLI 7.1 and Mac Sierra 10.12.5, the `InstallAnyware` crash without any error message. Reading the system requirements both 7.1 and 8.0 version of IBM MobileFirst does not support Mac Sierra (as OS) or iOS 10.3 (as runtime device).

Comment: @BernardoBaumblatt I followed the step what TyLy suggested. It worked for me. Created a studio on a mac with full internet connectivity and copied it over to the secure mac on their network. It works.... But the original pblm lies unresolved.

Comment: HI @DonWoodward, thank you for the tip. I don't have another Mac, but I open an PMR on IBM and receive a zip version of last MFP CLI and every thing works like a charme. So, I think that the problems is restricted on **InstallAnyware** used by IBM to bundle the software. Best regards.